# Filtering a dataframe with respect to the list of data

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am in trouble with making multi filtering in a dataframe wrt the list of data. My real data set is huge, so I created a fake one as below to make the question replicable.

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(Cluster=round(runif(2000,1,50)),
        Grup = paste0("Group",round(runif(2000,1,10))),
        ID = paste0("id",1:2000),
        Point1 = round(runif(2000,1,100)),
        Point2 = round(runif(2000,1,100)))

Cluster_grup <- list(List1 = data.frame( V1=c(47,35),V2=c(20,35)),
    List2 = data.frame(V1=c(10,5,6),V2=c(49,2,46),V3=c(11,12,13)),
    List3 = data.frame(V1=c(22,3),V2=c(18,18),V3=c(50,25),V4=c(6,7)))



Grup_info <- list(First = c("Group1","Group7"), 
             Second = c("Group4","Group5","Group3"),
             Third = c("Group10","Group8","Group1","Group6"))
```

I basically want to make a filtering with respect to the data inside `Grup_info` and `Cluster_grup`. For instance if we take the first elements of those two lists,

```
Grup_info[[1]]
"Group1" "Group7"

Cluster_grup [[1]]
  V1 V2
1 47 20
2 35 35
```

Then I need to filter and apply `expand.grid` like,

```
 df_sorted1 <- df %>% filter(.,Cluster == 47 & Grup=="Group1")  %>% 
              select(.,ID,Point1,Point2)
 df_sorted2 <-df %>% filter(.,Cluster == 20 & Grup=="Group7")  %>% 
              select(.,ID,Point1,Point2)

ep1 <- expand.grid(df_sorted1$ID,df_sorted2$ID)
ep2 <- expand.grid(df_sorted1$Point1,df_sorted2$Point1)
ep3 <- expand.grid(df_sorted1$Point2,df_sorted2$Point2)

data.frame(ep1, SumPoint1 = rowSums(ep2),SumPoint2 = rowSums(ep3))
```

So the very same thing will be applied while assigning `Cluster == 35` inside the `filter` function. Then I will bind those two dataframes as well.

But as you can see, the length of the groups are not equal. For example the third `Grup_info` has four elements inside it as the third `Cluster_grup` does.

At the end, I want to get a list, including three dataframes which are the  binded dataframes of `expand.grid` outputs.

I can actually achieve it by for loops or sapply family functions maybe, but I wonder if there exists a faster solution like a tidyverse approach or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to see you, maydin

I made the code you want probably.

### Data Input

```
set.seed(1)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(Cluster=round(runif(2000,1,50)),
                 Grup = paste0("Group",round(runif(2000,1,10))),
                 ID = paste0("id",1:2000),
                 Point1 = round(runif(2000,1,100)),
                 Point2 = round(runif(2000,1,100)))

Cluster_grup <- list(List1 = data.frame( V1=c(47,35),V2=c(20,35)),
                     List2 = data.frame(V1=c(10,5,6),V2=c(49,2,46),V3=c(11,12,13)),
                     List3 = data.frame(V1=c(22,3),V2=c(18,18),V3=c(50,25),V4=c(6,7)))



Grup_info <- list(List1 = c("Group1","Group7"), 
                  List2 = c("Group4","Group5","Group3"),
                  List3 = c("Group10","Group8","Group1","Group6"))
```

### Data merge

I merged `Cluster_grup` and `Grup_info`.

```
mergeGrp <-
  sapply(names(Grup_info), function(x){
    material <- Cluster_grup[[ x ]]
    colnames(material)<- Grup_info[[x]]
  return(material)
  })
> mergeGrp
$List1
  Group1 Group7
1     47     20
2     35     35

$List2
  Group4 Group5 Group3
1     10     49     11
2      5      2     12
3      6     46     13

$List3
  Group10 Group8 Group1 Group6
1      22     18     50      6
2       3     18     25      7
```

### Data handling

I used `RbindList` to merge all the result.
But if you don't want to that, you should manipulate yourself.

```
FinalResult = lapply(mergeGrp,function(x){
  tidyTest = x %>% tidyr::gather() %>% dplyr::group_by(key)
  result = NULL
  for (i in 1: NROW(x)){
    mate = tidyTest %>% filter(row_number() == i )
    condList = apply(mate,1,function(x){
                sprintf("( Cluster == %s & Grup == '%s' )",x[2],x[1])
                })
    filtered = lapply(condList, function(x){
                   df %>% filter_(x) %>% select(ID,Point1,Point2)}
                   )
    ep1 = filtered  %>% purrr::map(.,~.$ID) %>%
            as.vector() %>% expand.grid()
    ep2 = filtered  %>% purrr::map(.,~.$Point1) %>% as.vector() %>%
            expand.grid() %>% rowSums()
    ep3 = filtered  %>% purrr::map(.,~.$Point2) %>% as.vector() %>% 
            expand.grid() %>% rowSums()
    result = rbind(result,data.frame(ep1, SumPoint1 = ep2,SumPoint2 = ep3))
  }
  return(result)
}
)
#rbindlist(FinalResult)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @SteveLee. What is the `test` inside the loop ?

Comment: Oops, i am sorry i fixed the error and i delete `rbindlist` in the last. If you want to use it just changed to `rbindlist(FinalResult, fill = TRUE)`